# Create a loader stub for OutlookAddInBase

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create an Outlook 2013 addin which will load other managed addins from a specified location.  Basically a loader stub that knows how to find these other addins, load their assemblies, and register.

Here's a simple proof of concept:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;

[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.StartupObject(0)]
public class TestAddin : IAddInExtension, IExtension, EntryPoint, ISupportInitialize, IComponent, IDisposable, IBindableComponent
{
    private List<EntryPoint> entrypoints = new List<EntryPoint>();
    public TestAddin(Factory factory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Assembly asm = LoadAddinAssembly();
        foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes())
        {
            var attr = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Application.Runtime.StartupObjectAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (attr != null)
            {
                var ep = Activator.CreateInstance(
                    type, factory, serviceProvider)
                    as Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint;
                if (ep != null)
                {
                    entrypoints.Add(ep);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void BeginInit()
    {
        foreach (var inst in entrypoints)
            inst.BeginInit();
    }

    // Implement the rest of the interface methods similar to BeginInit above
}
```

Outlook constructs my class, my class loads the other addin assembly and creates the entry point, and then outlook calls the following 3 passthrough methods which I then call on to the other addin:

Initialize()

InitializeDataBindings()

FinishInitialization()

None of them create any errors, but after that, none of the passthrough methods get called, ever, and the addin I'm trying to load never does anything.

What is an official addin exposing to Outlook that I need to pass through?  Or is it even possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the parent service provider keeps track of each EntryPoint it created.  If you grab the IHostItemProvider like this:

```
serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IHostItemProvider))
```

you can use reflection to set "_entryPoints" (which is EntryPoint[]) to modify the list of entry points.  The calling code will then treat them as normal EntryPoints, no need to track them locally for passthrough calls.

The other critical detail is that _entryPoints[0] seems to be the only one that can register certain aspects of the UI, so it works best to derive from OutlookAddInBase (because it implements UI initialization logic) and make passthrough calls to the first entry point for CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() and CreateRibbonObjects().

Also, Ribbons and FormRegions must be defined in the manifest, I haven't found any way around that, so it also required creating a bunch of passthrough stubs that get hooked up through reflection.

Pretty brittle solution, but it seems to work for now (until Microsoft changes the internals).  And because of how _entryPoints[0] is so important, it looks like each loader stub can only load a single addin.

Answer (score 0):

If these other add-ins are not loading, you can do so via the Application.COMAddIns collection.  Get the COMAddIn object for the add-in you want to load and set COMAddIn.Connect = True.

Also see this for a supported way of calling the methods of another add-in:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice/

Comment: Thanks for the info.  At first glance it seems like it could have some relevance, but now that I read through the article, it turns out to be completely unrelated to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: COMAddins is a way to tell Outlook to load an already registered addin.  I'm trying to load an addin without registering it by loading the assembly within my already loaded and registered addin.  I want to be able to control which version of the external addin gets loaded at runtime.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "external addin" and how that is different from your add-in that's currently loaded? How is that different from a referenced assembly?  Perhaps using Reflection might be an option?

Comment: A loader stub doesn't contain any business logic, it exists solely to load another addin.  This other addin is external, not registered to Outlook.  Depending on certain database keys, I want to dynamically load a different version of the desired addin.  The answer I posted explains some of what's involved, but it has some issues.  I was hoping the link you posted might have been the official way to do that.